# How to mint tokens from existing contracts using Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, nft, arbitrum

*I am begginer so maybe I don’t understand this correctly.*

Well, some smart contract exists on [Arbiscan](https://arbiscan.io/address/0xFCf6bEf0579D4e6Da537B8154fa3b28102a574ab) **(it's not mine)**. I go to contract option and select write contract, connect to Metamask, then mint directly from contract on website.

*How can I do this using Solidity language?*

Comment: You need to fork mainnet. See the Foundry guide on [Forking Mode](https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/forking-mode.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the contract's code, paste it on remix, and create and instance of the contract on the same address as it is already deployed to (Also the same chain). Then, you will get the `mint()` function there and you can mint directly from there.

Answer (score 0):

The way you usually interact with contracts that are already deployed is by using the contract's address and its ABI (both are publicly available), then you can make your own frontend/client-application to interact with that contract.

You most probably won't need solidity to interact with an already deployed contract.

[This](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/calling-a-smart-contract-from-javascript/) should give you some more idea about the same.